# Custom font loads on defining @font-face or when used in font-family

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

As the title says, I have a lot of custom fonts to be referenced on a site where I will have different pages using a few of the fonts at once and not all.

I don't want to impact the site performance so want to know whether the browser loads the font files on defining the `@font-face` itself or waits for it to be first used in a `font-family`

Comment: That's what the Nertwork tab in your browser's F12 tools is for.

Answer (score 0):

On analyzing the network tab, it looks like the font files are not loaded unless and until one does not use them in the `font-family` thus it is safe to use as many declarations as `@font-face` without slowing down the site.